# Identical (?) C# and VB.NET LINQ queries return different results

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Probably something really easy, but I just can't see it...

I am replicating an MS Access query in LINQ. I wrote it in C# first to test it, because I prefer C#, then I translated it to VB.Net syntax.
As far as I can tell the two queries should be identical, but whilst the C# query returns the correct results, the VB.NET one returns zero results.

Can anybody see where the difference might be?

The C# query:

```
var table1 = dc.MainTable.Where(o => o.Year == 423).ToList().Select(o => new
{
    Key_ID = o.Key_ID.Value,
    CropID = o.CropID.Value,
    GroupID = o.GroupID.Value,
    Surface1 = o.Surface1.Value,
    Surface2 = o.Surface2.Value
});

var table2 = dc.OtherTable.Where(o => o.Year == 423).ToList().Select(o => new
{
    Key_ID = o.Key_ID.Value,
    CropID = int.Parse(o.SAKU_CD),
    GroupID = int.Parse(o.SAN_DAN_NO),
    Surface1 = Convert.ToDouble(o.KEIHAN_MEN.Value),
    Surface2 = Convert.ToDouble(o.SAKU_MEN.Value)
});

var output = table1.Join(table2, t1 => new 
{ 
    t1.Key_ID, 
    t1.CropID, 
    t1.GroupID, 
    t1.Surface1, 
    t1.Surface2 
}, 
t2 => new 
{ 
    t2.Key_ID, 
    t2.CropID, 
    t2.GroupID, 
    t2.Surface1, 
    t2.Surface2 
}, (t1, t2) => new OutputDataType() 
{ 
    Key_ID = t1.Key_ID, 
    Year = 423 
}).ToList();
```

The VB.NET query:

```
Dim table1 = MainTable.Where(Function(o) o.Year.Value = 423).ToList().Select(Function(o) New With
{
    .Key_ID = o.Key_ID.Value,
    .CropID = o.CropID.Value,
    .GroupID = o.GroupID.Value,
    .Surface1 = o.Surface1.Value,
    .Surface2 = o.Surface2.Value
}).ToList()

Dim table2 = OtherTable.Where(Function(o) o.Year.Value = 423).ToList().Select(Function(o) New With
{
    .Key_ID = o.Key_ID.Value,
    .CropID = Convert.ToInt32(o.SAKU_CD),
    .GroupID = Convert.ToInt32(o.SAN_DAN_NO),
    .Surface1 = Convert.ToDouble(o.KEIHAN_MEN.Value),
    .Surface2 = Convert.ToDouble(o.SAKU_MEN.Value)
}).ToList()

Dim output = table1.Join(table2, Function(t1) New With
{
    t1.Key_ID,
    t1.CropID,
    t1.GroupID,
    t1.Surface1,
    t1.Surface2
}, Function(t2) New With
{
    t2.Key_ID,
    t2.CropID,
    t2.GroupID,
    t2.Surface1,
    t2.Surface2
}, Function(t1, t2) New OutputDataType With {.Key_ID = t1.Key_ID, .Year = 423}).ToList()
```

In both C# and VB.Net `table1` and `table2` are the same, so it must be the `Join` which fails.

EDIT

I just changed the `Join` in VB.Net to query syntax, like this:

```
Dim output = From t1 In MainTable
                 Join t2 In OtherTable
                 On t1.Key_ID Equals t2.Key_ID And t1.GroupID Equals t2.GroupID And t1.CropID Equals t2.CropID And t1.Surface1 Equals t2.Surface1 And t1.Surface2 Equals t2.Surface2
                 Select New OutputDataTypeData With {.Key_ID = t1.Key_ID, .Year = 423}
```

Which gives the correct result. But I really don't get how this is different from the extension method `Join` syntax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use the [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) extension method, the keys you provide as `outerKeySelector` and `innerKeySelector` arguments are compared using the `Equals` method.

But C# and VB.Net handle **anonymous types** differently here:

**C#**

```
var a = new {Foo = 1, Bar = 2 };
var b = new {Foo = 1, Bar = 2 };
bool result = a.Equals(b); // true
```

**VB.Net**

```
Dim a = new with {.Foo = 1, .Bar = 2}
Dim b = new with {.Foo = 1, .Bar = 2}
Dim result = a.Equals(b) ' False '
```

What's happening here?

C# uses *value equality* to compare the two objects, comparing the values of the properties.

VB.Net uses *reference equality* to compare the two objects, hence the result is `False`.

To have your code work, you have to explicitly tell VB.Net to compare the properties using the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) keyword:

> Key properties differ from non-key properties in several fundamental ways:
>
> - Only the values of key properties are compared in order to determine whether two instances are equal.
> - The values of key properties are read-only and cannot be changed.
> - Only key property values are included in the compiler-generated hash code algorithm for an anonymous type.

```
Dim a = new with {Key .Foo = 1, Key .Bar = 2}
Dim b = new with {Key .Foo = 1, Key .Bar = 2}
Dim result = a.Equals(b) # True
```

The query syntax works because in this case you are not comparing the anonymous types/objects but simply `int`s and `double`s.

Comment: Thanks!! I already got caught out by the `Key` keyword before. I think I'm gonna print out your explanation and sticker it to my PC, so I don't forget about this anymore. Thanks so much!