# Can a particular constructor argument of an injected SUT using Autodata xUnit Theories?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, xunit, autofixture

Consider the following test,

```cs
[Theory, MyConventions]
public void GetClientExtensionReturnsCorrectValue(BuilderStrategy sut)
{
    var expected = ""; // <--??? the value injected into BuilderStrategy
    var actual = sut.GetClientExtension();
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

and the custom attribute I'm using:

```cs
public class MyConventionsAttribute : AutoDataAttribute {
    public MyConventionsAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization())) {}
}
```

and the SUT:

```cs
class BuilderStrategy {
    private readonly string _clientID;
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;
    public void BuilderStrategy(string clientID, IDependency dependency) {
        _clientID = clientID;
        _dependency = dependency;      
    }
    public string GetClientExtension() {
        return _clientID.Substring(_clientID.LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
    }
}
```

I need to know what value was injected into the constructor parameter `clientID` so that I can use it to compare with the output of `GetClientExtension`.  Is it possible to do this while still writing this style of test where the SUT is injected into the test method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you expose the injected `clientID` (and `dependency` as well) as read-only properties, you can always query their values:

```
public class BuilderStrategy {
    private readonly string _clientID;
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;
    public void BuilderStrategy(string clientID, IDependency dependency) {
        _clientID = clientID;
        _dependency = dependency;      
    }
    public string GetClientExtension() {
        return _clientID.Substring(_clientID.LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
    }

    public string ClientID
    {
        get { return _clientID; }
    }

    public IDependency Dependency
    {
        get { return _dependency; }
    }
}
```

This [*doesn't* break encapsulation, but is rather known as Structural Inspection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/04/structural-inspection).

With this change, you could now rewrite the test like this:

```
[Theory, MyConventions]
public void GetClientExtensionReturnsCorrectValue(BuilderStrategy sut)
{
    var expected = sut.ClientID.Substring(sut.ClientID.LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
    var actual = sut.GetClientExtension();
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Some people don't like duplicating production code in the unit test, but I would rather argue that if you follow Test-Driven Development, it's the production code that duplicates the test code.

In any case, this is a technique known as [Derived Value](http://xunitpatterns.com/Derived%20Value.html). In my opinion, [as long as it retains a cyclomatic complexity of 1, we can still trust the test](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/02/why-trust-tests). Additionally, as long as the duplicated code only appears in two places, the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28computer_programming%29) suggests that we should keep it like that.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, also for the embedded references. In using Structural Inspection, should the readonly properties be part of the interface or only the implementations under test (assuming there exists an `IBuilderStrategy` which `BuilderStrategy` implements)? Also, I would think that it would be better to expose these properties *as the need arises* in unit testing, rather than expose all dependencies as a routine matter (although, I suppose that in practicing TDD, this would all happen naturally). Do you have an opinion on any of that?

Comment: Using Derived Value it seems possible to get [False Negative](http://xunitpatterns.com/false%20negative.html) results if your tests are written in C# and your SUT is written in VB.NET. In my code, R# suggested using `StringComparison.Orginal` with `LastIndexOf` in the C# test, but not in the VB.NET-written SUT. The R# suggestion isn't the problem, but it indicates that using Derived Value either tightly couples you to a particular .NET language, or expose you to [sneaky differences that exist between languages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14931907/533958)

Comment: The property is part of the concrete class: "Ultimately, adding a property to a concrete class has no impact on the exposed interface."

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic about False Negatives... If you follow TDD and the Red/Green/Refactor cycle, you should see the test fail before you make it pass. That provides good protection against False Negatives. Ultimately, the test *is* the specification; if you end up writing a different implementation in your production code, it doesn't really matter as long as it matches the specification.

Comment: Point taken re: TDD & Red/Green/Refactor. Sadly, I'm having to reverse-engineer this on existing code ;) So, in creating the *Derived Value*, it is only important that the code used to create it is *equivalent* to that of the implementation, not that it is an *exact copy* (allowing for different .NET languages to be used). The burden is then shifted (rightly so) to the tests to account for any bizarre edge cases you can think of. Testing specific values could then be done with a different test using inline data, when random values for (`ClientID`, in this example) are not explicit enough.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing Characterization Tests: http://agileinaflash.blogspot.dk/2009/02/writing-characterization-tests.html

Comment: You're right - thanks for another link to a great resource I'd not seen before!